# I need to create a function that returns a plain javascript string that is indexed by 'name', and contains all the 'props'

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My code seems to be right, but it isn't returning a ':' but a ',' at certain places of the Json result. please see desired result in the code comments.

I also don't like the "replaces" I coded to remove the array's brackets from the Json expression and I shouldn't modify the JSON string. Is there a more elegant way to do it?

```html
    // JSON Object  
    var items  = [
      {
        name: "item 1",
        id: 2,
        props: {
          a: "a prop1",
          b: "b prop1",
        },
        values: [1, 2, 3],
      },
      {
        name: "item 2",
        id: 3,
        props: {
          a: "a prop2",
          b: "b prop2",
        },
        values: [6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
      },
      {
        name: "item 3",
        id: 4,
        props: {
          a: "a prop3",
          c: "c prop3",
        },
        values: [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      },
    ];

    export function getObject(items) {
    
    var arr = [];
    
      for(var i in items){
        arr.push(items[i].name);
        arr.push(items[i].props);
      }
    
      var myJSON = JSON.stringify(arr).toString();
      
      var test = myJSON.replace("[","{").replace("]","}"); // I couldn't find another way to extract the array data from the array brackets.
      
      var test2 = JSON.stringify(test);
    
    // test2 is returning: "{\"item 1\",{\"a\":\"a prop1\",\"b\":\"b prop1\"},\"item 2\",{\"a\":\"a prop2\",\"b\":\"b prop2\"},\"item 3\",{\"a\":\"a prop3\",\"c\":\"c prop3\"}}"  
    // but it's expected:  "{\"item 1\":{\"a\":\"a prop1\",\"b\":\"b prop1\"},\"item 2\":{\"a\":\"a prop2\",\"b\":\"b prop2\"},\"item 3\":{\"a\":\"a prop3\",\"c\":\"c prop3\"}}"
          
       return test2;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please update your post to include the actual code? Also, making your own text not look like block quotes is a good idea (even if you paste from an email, make sure to update the text to use the [syntax used by the site you're posting to](/editing-help))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.map` to transform each item into an object, which has one property, whose key is the `item.name`, and value is the `item.props` object:

```js
const getObject = items => items.map(item => ({ [item.name]: item.props }));

// JSON Object  
var items = [{
    name: "item 1",
    id: 2,
    props: {
      a: "a prop1",
      b: "b prop1",
    },
    values: [1, 2, 3],
  },
  {
    name: "item 2",
    id: 3,
    props: {
      a: "a prop2",
      b: "b prop2",
    },
    values: [6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  },
  {
    name: "item 3",
    id: 4,
    props: {
      a: "a prop3",
      c: "c prop3",
    },
    values: [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  },
];


console.log(getObject(items));
```

If you actually need a JSON string and not an object, then put `JSON.stringify` around it. (remember: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).)

```js
const getObject = items => JSON.stringify(items.map(item => ({ [item.name]: item.props })));

// JSON Object  
var items = [{
    name: "item 1",
    id: 2,
    props: {
      a: "a prop1",
      b: "b prop1",
    },
    values: [1, 2, 3],
  },
  {
    name: "item 2",
    id: 3,
    props: {
      a: "a prop2",
      b: "b prop2",
    },
    values: [6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  },
  {
    name: "item 3",
    id: 4,
    props: {
      a: "a prop3",
      c: "c prop3",
    },
    values: [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  },
];


console.log(getObject(items));
```

Comment: Your solution creates the function itself and maps the fields I need, which is great, but I was given an existent function and I'm just struggling to return the expected JSON string: "{\"item 1\":{\"a\":\"a prop1\",\"b\":\"b prop1\"},\"item 2\":{\"a\":\"a prop2\",\"b\":\"b prop2\"},\"item 3\":{\"a\":\"a prop3\",\"c\":\"c prop3\"}}". Your solution brings the array brackets in front of it and it isn't matching with the desired string value.